# How to get blank page or echo "all fields are required" when I click login in my form?

Tags: php, sql

**Whenever I run this code and click login it echos "wellcome you can continue to browse" without even giving name or pass, but I want to echo it blank or just give me a message like "all
fields are required".**

```
<html>
<title>Login</title>
<form action="Login.php"=method="post">
    Username:<input type="text" name="u"><br>
    Password:<input type="password" name="p"><br>
    <input type="Submit" value="Login"><br>
</form>

<?php
$c = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($c, "mobile shop");
if (isset($_POST['u'])) {
    $a = $_POST['u'];
    $b = $_POST['p'];
    $q = mysqli_query($c, "select * from login");
    $x = 0;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
        if (($a == $row['Name']) && ($b == $row['Pass'])) {
            echo "Wellcome " . $row['Name'] . "<br> You Can continue to browse <br>
<a href='SmartphoneID.php'>Input Smart Phone ID </a> <br>
<a href='allsmartphones.php'>Show All Smart Phones </a>";
            $x = 1;
        }
    }

    if ($x == 0) {
        echo "Your Username or Password is wrong <br>
Don't have an account? <a href='Sign UP.php'>Register here</a>";
    }
}

mysqli_close($c);
?>

</html>
```

[image: This is the output]

Comment: You need to test for `!empty` instead of `isset`. Even if an array element is an empty string, it is still considered as set. And you need to check both fields explicitly.

Comment: Thanks its working now, but what if I want to put a condition here to get a message like "error: all fields are required" whenever a field is blank?

Comment: It's possible to do manually (if you detect some of them are empty, you show the message) or let HTML do it for you (shown in the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this in your HTML. It will say if you leave it empty, that it is a required field.

```
Username:<input type="text" name="u" required="required">
```